# Why can't I render a scene twice?

Tags: rendering

When I render a scene once fully, but want to change it, I can't render it again; it just "renders" the previous render.

Comment: Start a new general file, render, move the cube, and render again.  Does the problem persist?  I know you lack the rep to comment but you can use the Edit link at the bottom of your post to provide more info and it will be bumped back up in the active questions.

Comment: @allen No worries, everyone can comment on their own posts :)

Comment: Do you have any strips on the vse?

Comment: It won't work even with a load of modifications, and I do have a strip on the VSE.